While opening browser in existing browser this error shows in console?
This error >Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9183
from chrome not reachable
https://prnt.sc/yAdaKD0aH4jk
I want to do automation in existing broswer which was open manually

Can you share the code snippet? How are you instantiating the chrome browser?

You can't do that unless it was launched in dev-mode with that port set for the debugger.
